# How do I change passphrase on Openshift?

Tags: git, openshift

I am on a windows machine. I am very new to Linux systems. I am using Git-bash for windows to manage my project. the project is hosted on Openshift, But I am unable to find any documentation about changing the passphrase key. I have my current passphrase key but how do I remove or change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passphrase on your ssh key has nothing to do with OpenShift Online.  The answer to this question (https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase) on ServerFault should get you fixed up.